# Reuse texture and vertices in OpenGL

Tags: java, opengl, opengl-compat

I am trying to make a simple 2D game, and I store the world in a 2D array of Block (an enum, with each value having its texture).

Since these are all simple opaque tiles, when rendering I sort them by texture and then render them by translating to their coordinate. However, I also need to specify the texture coordinates and the vertex for each tile that I draw, even though these are also the same.

Here's what I currently have:

```java
public static void render() {
    // Sorting...
    for(SolidBlock block : xValues.keySet()) {
        block.getTexture().bind();
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);

        for(int coordinateIndex = 0; coordinateIndex < xValues.get(block).size(); coordinateIndex++) {
            int x = xValues.get(block).get(coordinateIndex);
            int y = yValues.get(block).get(coordinateIndex);
            glTranslatef(x, y, Integer.MIN_VALUE);
            // Here I use MIN_VALUE because I'll later have to do z sorting with other tiles
            glBegin(GL_QUADS);
            loadModel();
            glEnd();
            glLoadIdentity();
        }

        xValues.get(block).clear();
        yValues.get(block).clear();
    }
}

private static void loadModel() {
    glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
    glVertex2f(0, 0);
    glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
    glVertex2f(1, 0);
    glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
    glVertex2f(1, 1);
    glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
    glVertex2f(0, 1);
}
```

I'd like to know if it is possible to put loadModel() before the main loop, to avoid having to load the model thousands of times with the same Data, and also what else could be moved to make it as fast as possible!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Some quick optimizations:**

- `glTexParameteri` only needs to be called once per parameter per texture. You should put it in the part of your code where you load the textures.
- You can draw multiple quads in one `glBegin`/`glEnd` pair simply by adding more vertices. However, you cannot do any coordinate changes between `glBegin` and `glEnd` (such as `glTranslatef` or `glLoadIdentity` or `glPushMatrix`) so you'll have to pass `x` and `y` to your `loadModel` function (which really should be called `addQuad` for accuracy). It's also not allowed to rebind textures between `glBegin`/`glEnd`, so you'll have to use one set of `glBegin`/`glEnd` per texture.
- Minor, but instead of calling `xValues.get(block)` a whole bunch of times, just say `List<Integer> blockXValues = xValues.get(block)` at the beginning of your outer loop and then use `blockXValues` from there on.

**Some more involved optimizations:**

- Legacy OpenGL has draw lists, which are basically macros for OpenGL. You can make OpenGL record all the OpenGL calls you're doing between `glNewList` and `glEndList` (with some exceptions), and store them somehow. The next time you want to run those exact OpenGL calls, you can use `glCallList` to make OpenGL do just that for you. Some optimizations will be done on the draw list in order to speed up subsequent draws.
- Texture switching is relatively expensive, which you're probably already aware of since you sorted your quads by texture, but there is a better solution than sorting textures: Put all your textures into a single [texture atlas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texture_atlas). You'll want to store the subtexture coordinates of each block inside your `SolidBlock`s, and then pass `block` to `addQuad` as well so you can pass the appropriate subtexture coordinates to `glTexCoord2f`. Once you've done that, you don't need to sort by texture anymore and can just iterate over x and y coordinates.

**Good practices:**

- Only use `glLoadIdentity` once per frame, at the beginning of your draw process. Then use `glPushMatrix` paired with `glPopMatrix` to save and restore the state of matrices. That way the inner parts of your code don't need to know about the matrix transformations the outer parts may or may not have done beforehand.
- Don't use `Integer.MIN_VALUE` as a vertex coordinate. Use a constant of your own choosing, preferably one that won't make your depth range huge (the last two arguments to `glOrtho` which I assume you're using). Depth buffer precision is limited, you'll run into Z-fighting issues if you try to use Z coordinates of 1 or 2 or so after setting your Z range from `Integer.MIN_VALUE` to `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. Also, you're using `float` coordinates, so `int` constants don't make sense here anyway.

Here's the code after a quick pass (without the texture atlas changes):

```
private static final float BLOCK_Z_DEPTH = -1; // change to whatever works for you
private int blockCallList;
private boolean regenerateBlockCallList; // set to true whenever you need to update some blocks

public static void init() {
    blockCallList = glGenLists(1);
    regenerateBlockCallList = true;
}

public static void render() {
    if (regenerateBlockCallList) {
        glNewList(blockCallList, GL_COMPILE_AND_EXECUTE);
        drawBlocks();
        glEndList();

        regenerateBlockCallList = false;
    } else {
        glCallList(blockCallList);
    }
}

private static void drawBlocks() {
    // Sorting...

    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(0, 0, BLOCK_Z_DEPTH);

    for (SolidBlock block : xValues.keySet()) {
        List<Integer> blockXValues = xValues.get(block);
        List<Integer> blockYValues = yValues.get(block);

        block.getTexture().bind();
        glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        for(int coordinateIndex = 0; coordinateIndex < blockXValues.size(); coordinateIndex++) {
            int x = blockXValues.get(coordinateIndex);
            int y = blockYValues.get(coordinateIndex);
            addQuad(x,y);
        }
        glEnd();

        blockXValues.clear();
        blockYValues.clear();
    }

    glPopMatrix();

}

private static void addQuad(float x, float y) {
    glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
    glVertex2f(x, y);
    glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
    glVertex2f(x+1, y);
    glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
    glVertex2f(x+1, y+1);
    glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
    glVertex2f(x, y+1);
}
```

With modern OpenGL (vertex buffers, shaders and instancing instead of display lists, matrix transformations and passing vertices one by one) you'd approach this problem very differently, but I'll keep that beyond the scope of my answer.

Comment: Really useful and explanatory answer, thank you very much!!